# Is there a way to find out which maven artifact a class is in?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, intellij-14

I'm trying to upgrade our Spring version and use Spring IO Platform BOM to do so, but a few of our classes have gone missing (moved into other artifacts) or are no longer dependencies of some thing I was pulling in. I'm trying to find out which package they were originally part of (one example is CSVStrategy ). Some of these dependencies such as `WhitespaceTokenizer` have over a dozen artifact names that could be supplying it, and in order to find the correct upgrade path I need to figure out where it's currently coming from.

Comment: Does [searching by class name](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) of search.maven.org help? You also may want to read release notes, they should mention (re)moved classes.

Comment: again, not helpful, because I want to know what I have, not what I might get, the specific class mentioned seems to be an indirect dependency or something, I can't read release notes unless I can figure out the thing i'm using.

Comment: Assuming you are in Eclipse: position mouse cursor on class name in your source code and press F3. Anyway, Java doesn't operate with short class names, but with fully-qualified class names, so there must be an import for that class that states the package name. There should only be one artifact in your classpath that provides this class.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way could be to get the resource (class) location. If the class comes from a jar file you would at least get the jar name. From that you should be able to identify the maven artifact.

```
someClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
```

Or with a ResourceLoader and a logger you could print a list of all classes on the classpath / servlet-path.

```
@Autowired 
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public void printResourceLocations() {
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader);
    Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:com/**/*.class"));
    for (Resource resource : resources) {
        log.info(resource.getURI()); 
        // Not sure if that works, probably getFile() is ok?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [JBoss Tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/) for this type of task in the past.  I don't think it's being actively maintained any longer, however it still works for me.  Here's the config I use.  Note, I had to add this to my POM's build section, even though the goal 'report' seems to imply it is a report plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.tattletale</groupId>
  <artifactId>tattletale-maven</artifactId>
  <!-- The version of the plugin you want to use -->
  <version>1.2.0.Beta2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
  <!-- This is the location which will be scanned for generating tattletale reports -->
    <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/lib</source>
    <!-- This is where the reports will be generated -->
    <destination>${project.build.directory}/site/tattletale</destination>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You could also try [jHades](http://blog.jhades.org/classnotfoundexception-jhades-jar-hell-made-easy/).  I haven't had a chance to use it yet, it is on my list of things to investigate.